# Terminology question regarding looping thru an NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, terminology

When you have an NSArray and you want to evaluate and change the elements, you can't change the array from inside the loop. So, you create a mutable copy that **can** be changed.

code example:

```
NSMutableArray *bin = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil];
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a1", @"b2", @"c3", @"e4", nil];

NSMutableArray *listHolder = list; // can't mutate 'list' within loop so create a holder

for (int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++) {
    [listHolder replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[bin objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

What is that second array **listHolder** called? I mean, what term is used to refer to an array in this context.

Comment: Did you mean to make `bin` and `list` NSArrays?

Comment: would that change your answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context `listHolder` would be called a *copy*.

Your code has a bug though. This line is not actually making a copy, it is only letting `listHolder` and `list` both reference the same array object:

```
NSMutableArray *listHolder = list;
```

This would be an actual copy:

```
NSMutableArray *listHolder = [list mutableCopy];
```

Make sure that you use `mutableCopy` and not just `copy` if you want the copy to be mutable. The `copy` method will return immutable variants on all mutable classes such as `NSMutableSet`, `NSMutableDictionary`, and so forth.

Also as others have noted it is only inside the `for (item in collection)` loop that the enumerated collection can not be mutated. In a normal `for (;;)` mutation is perfectly ok, but can lead to strange result if the number of items in the collection changes.

Comment: Thanks for the bug catch. I normally use (item in collection) when possible and picked a poor code example. I'm glad I did as it exposed an error in my thinking about pointers.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly valid:

```
NSMutableArray *bin = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"1", …, @"7", nil];
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a1", …, @"e4", nil];

// NSInteger should be used instead of int
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [list count]; i++) {
    [list replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[bin objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

You're not allowed to change the array inside a `for … in` or `NSEnumerate` loop, but using an index is perfectly valid.

What troubles me is your misunderstanding of pointers.
If it were a loop in which you weren't allowed to mutate the array this wouldn't copy the array but only the pointer to the array, effectively modifying the array you're not allowed to. *(I'm not even sure if this works.)*

Instead of just copying the pointer

```
// can't mutate 'list' within loop so create a holder
NSMutableArray *listHolder = list;
```

make a true copy:

```
NSMutableArray *copy = [[list mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

In case I really have to make a copy I try to name it according to its content. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *views;
NSMutableArray *reorderedViews = [views mutableCopy];

// reorder reorderedViews
```

Sometimes it's hard to find a good enough name, then I usually just use `nameCopy`.

Comment: This is useful information and thank you for that but you didn't answer the question. I picked a bad code example and derailed the question. At least I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

There is not specific stylistic or common name for this that is universally used, it is your code afterall, and if there appropriate terms for them use them.

Having said that generally if you don't have specific names in this sort of situation then people refer to the original list as the "source" (src) and the final list as "destination" (dst), just like in a memory blitting style operation.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary mutable copy of the original NSArray would be how I would refer to it.